# .htaccess Pretty URL rewrite for PHP pages in a subfolder?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I've got the following directory setup:

`http://www.mysite.com/public/`

I'm using the following rewrite to remove the 'public' folder from visible URLs:

```
#rewrite the URL to display the subdirectory as the main directory for all links
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

This works great, and redirects everything correctly. However, I also want to rewrite some of the dynamic pages that live in the 'public' subfolder as well, but am having trouble getting any of the rewrites I've found to work in conjunction with the above rule.

For example, with the above subdirectory rewrite rule in place, going to a URL like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/item.php?id=1&name=item_name
```

...should be rewritten to something like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/items/item_name
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#rewrite the URL to display the subdirectory as the main directory for all links
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
Rewriterule ^(?!public/|prints/)(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /*item\.php\?id=([^&]*)&name=([^&]*)\s [NC]
Rewriterule ^ /prints/%1/%2? [R,L,NC]

Rewriterule ^prints/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ public/item.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

PS: Make sure your static includes like css, js, images etc have absolute path rather than a relative one.

Comment: That syntax seems close, but together with the original rule it's still not rewriting the URL. It still appears in it's full `http://www.mysite.com/item.php?id=1&name=item_name` format. Do I need to put a separate .htaccess file in the subfolder 'public'?

Comment: No it should all be in same .htaccess file. Can you pls try my edited code now.

Comment: Ah I overlooked another fact,  pls check it again.

Comment: Still not working. I still need to have the original 3 lines for the subfolder-to-root rewrite rule working in tandem with the actual PHP URL rewrites...

Comment: Hmm I have tested it properly this time. Looks like some other conflicting rule is creating issues. Can you post access.log or error.log matching entries here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7635/discussion-between-mindsculpt-and-anubhava)

Comment: I posted the change on chat as well that you didn't take my answer in entirety. You need to replace your existing rule with first rule here.